# Cant flash my firmware on my huawei p8 lite ( Model Num: ALE-UL00___Build num: ALE-UL00C00B230) Also cant find firmware avalable anywhere?

Tags: boot-loop, huawei, usb-debugging, device-firmware

I have been at this for almost 2 days straight now, Here is the scenario: I bought a phone off of E-bay, but it has a wierd firmware on it which didnt allow me to connect to wifi, but instead had a Wlan only option, and no wifi to be found anywhere. It also had all these wierd chinese apps on it with tons of ads bombarding my screen. and no wifi to be found anywhere.

So i decided to load a different version firmware off of an SD card, and not only did the new firmware not work, but it overwrote the old firmware aswell. Now i'm stuck in a bootloop. I have tried about 10 different firmware's by now and i cant get my device to successfully install it. So then i turned to Windows Powershell.

I followed online instructions, my computer detects my phone in Fastboot mode, but i cant for the love of GOD get my commands applied, it keeps saying:"" **FAILED (remote: Command not allowed)**"" '. Another note, before this whole mess, i enabled USB debugging, but i couldnt find an **""Enable OEM ""** slider, I also cant find my exact Firmware anywhere. (So i just played around with simar titled Frimwares. )

**(My Model Number is: ALE-UL00)

(And my Build number is: ALE-UL00C00B230)**

**So now my phone is stuck with no OS/Firmware, and i cant use POWERSHELL because i dont have OEM enabled. SOME PLEASE TELL ME WHAT I CAN DO TO FIX THIS. My current fastboot screen sais : **PHONE locked** ** does that have something to do with the OEM setting and is that why i cant apply my Powershell Commands? please advise me, IM BEGGING YOU INTERNET!!!

Comment: In mid 2018 Huawei has stopped allowing to unlock their devices. If your latest firmware had been created after that date most likely Huawei has removed the OEM unlock option.

Comment: i see, but the firmware i need is from november 2016

Comment: ive been awake for 34 hours trying to flash this damn phone lol

Comment: @Wian i doubt you understand. your bootloader must unlocked. you can't flash from fastboot on locked bootloader. buy unlock code from 3rd party, Huawei doesn't provide unlock codes anymore

Comment: There is a way to get your bootloader unlocked, it's called slock unlocking.